# html css increase parents height if child height increases on scroll

Tags: html, css

Here is my html mockup

```css
html, body {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.left {
  flex: 0.5;
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
}

.right {
  flex: 0.5;
  height: 1300px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  
    <div class="left"></div>

    <div class="right"></div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here class "right" has height of 1300px which makes scroll on to the window.
When I scroll the parent "container" is not as the height of "right".

I want the parent "container" height to be increased if child "right" height is increased".

How to achieve this ??

Comment: `height: 100%;` --> `min-height: 100%;` ?

Comment: @Temani Good answer ..  Add min-height to container class. That is  `.container {min-height: 100%;}` exactly works :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif didn't work .. child appears to have more height than parent

Comment: it does work based on your explanation. If not, make your question clear and show us the intended resutl

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand what you mean, but test this code..

```
.container {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    background-color: red;
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap:30px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
 }

 .left {
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
 }

 .right {
    background: green;
 }
```